# Swagger type discriminator alias or mapping

Tags: inheritance, swagger, discriminator

I have a Swagger 2.0 definition like so:

```
definitions:
  Foo:
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
      fooType:
        type: string
    required:
      - name
      - fooType
    discriminator: fooType

  StringFoo:
    type: object
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/Foo'
    properties:
      values:
        type: array
        items: 
          type: string

  BooleanFoo:
    type: object
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/Foo'
    properties:
      values:
        type: array
        items: 
          type: boolean
```

I want my API clients to be able to construct (for instance) an array consisting of different Foo objects. To do so, they would write something like:

```
[
  {
    "name":"bar",
    "fooType":"StringFoo",
    "value":"baz"
  },
  {
    "name":"quux",
    "fooType":"BooleanFoo",
    "value":true
  }
]
```

However, I think it looks rather ugly when the client has to reference the name of the definition (StringFoo and BooleanFoo), especially for clients who implement without the Swagger definition at hand. Instead it would be cleaner and simpler if the fooType variable could have values "string" and "boolean". I realize I would need to have some mapping from "string" to "StringFoo" and from "boolean" to "BooleanBar". Some kind of alias that only applies to the Foo discriminator.

I could name my definitions "string" and "boolean" (is that even allowed?), but it would only work for one type schema and I have this issue in multiple places of my API.

Is there a way to create such a mapping or aliases with Swagger, or is there a common workaround? If not, does anyone have a recommendation for another tool that would allow me to define such relationships?

Comment: I ended up using JSONSchema instead, using "oneOf" to define all possible subtypes, and then implementing code to discern between the different types in my server. Not pretty, but it works.

Comment: I am facing a very similar dilemma, can you provide a small example of how you got around this issue? I am a little confused reading the comment. Thanks!

Comment: Side question, you say your schema is 2.0 in your question, yet in the comment above, you refer to the "oneOf" feature which, AFAIK, is a 3.0 feature?

Comment: We never managed to get around it. We scrapped Swagger 2.0 altogether and used JSONSchema instead. JSONSchema supports the "oneOf" feature that Swagger 2.0 does not have. However, Swagger 3.0 (renamed OpenAPI) seems to support "oneOf" so maybe that would work for you?